# Converting 720p screen to relative point on larger display

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm trying to create a remote desktop access tool in Java (more of an experiment than anything really), but i'm having trouble converting the point in which is clicked to a location on the main screen. Let me explain.

[image: Here's an example of how it looks]

Here's an example of how the tool looks (for now). 
The screen capture window is 1280x720, and the actual screens vary in size, how can I get the location of where the mouse is and change it to the same location on the main screen?

e.g. if I click on the apple logo on the screen capture window, it should move my mouse and click on the apple logo on the main screen. I just can't figure out how to get the point in the window, and translate it to the same point on the main screen!

EDIT: Here is what i'm trying to do atm:

```
MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            PacketMoveMouse packetMoveMouse = new PacketMoveMouse(address, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
            sendPacket(address, packetMoveMouse);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Point point = this.getPoint(e.getPoint());
            PacketClickMouse packetClickMouse = new PacketClickMouse(address, point.getX(), point.getY(), e.getButton());
            sendPacket(address, packetClickMouse);
        }

        private Point getPoint(Point point) {
            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, panel);
            return point;
        }
    };
```

I also tried without converting the point, i was just trying various things. It moves the mouse correctly, but to the wrong point.

I also tried to convert it to a point on the main screen using some basic math, but i think my logic flawed, here is what i tried:

```
            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            int x = ((PacketMoveMouse) packet).getX();
            int y = ((PacketMoveMouse) packet).getY();
            double xRatio = (screenRect.getWidth() / 1280);
            double yRatio = (screenRect.getHeight() / 720);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove((int) ((x * xRatio)), (int) ((y * yRatio)));
```

This is when i just send the regular point to the client then change to to a relative point once it's received. The display screen of the client is 1280x720 currently.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I just can't figure out how to get the point in the window"* Are you saying that is **part of what you cannot figure out**, or is it simply there to lead into what you are **actually having trouble with**? .. Never mind, the MCVE should clear that up.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I updated the post with some code I tried. Thanks

Comment: *"I updated the post with some code I tried."* Try **reading** the documents in the first 2 links.

Comment: Well it's nothing that i really need to reproduce... I'm just trying to convert a point on a 1280x720 to the equivalent point on a larger display, that's what i've tried.

Comment: *"Well it's nothing that i really need to reproduce..."* Do you 'need' an answer? Most people do not give a question serios attention until there is an MCVE / SSCCE present. In fact, there are 2 close reasons that include 'no MCVE' as party of the description.

Comment: I don't think you understand, i'm not trying to reproduce anything, i'm asking how would you convert MouseEvent#getPoint to a relative size depending on the display...

Comment: *"i'm not trying to reproduce anything,"* I don't understand what you mean by that. An advantage of creating an MCVE is so that **other people** (you know, those people you hope can *answer* the question) can reproduce it! Incidentally, I actually copy/pasted part of your code snippet into a working app. to check the integer division was resulting in doubles as expected. It was, so that suspicion was a dead end. But I'm not prepared to give the question more thought until *you* make it easy for me to test. Heck, grab a screenshot, scale it and display it, add a mouse listener ..

Comment: .. the lot to create an MCVE should only take 40-50 lines of code in total. If you're not willing to put that much effort to enlist the active help of others, fine, but don't expect high quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

To get your mouse CURRENT coordinates

```
 int mouseX;
 int mouseY;

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();

}
```

Comment: I am aware of how to get the point, but i'm trying to convert it to a point on the main screen (from 1280x720 to whatever resolution the client screen is).